# Is there any way to set table column width dynamically per column via CSS/LESS?

Tags: css, less

What I mean is, is that if there are 4 columns to a table, the column's width would be at maximum 25% of the table's width. If it was 3 columns, then 33%. Two columns, 50%. 10 columns? 10%. The maximum width for the table is predetermined at 500px (for the sake of this example) and will always stay, at maximum, 500px. LESS is being used.

Comment: So basically you want equal column widths?

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  table.one-fourth tr td { width:25%; }
</style>

<table class="one-fourth" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>

<style>
  table.one-third tr td { width:33%; }
</style>

<table class="one-third" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively you can just use

```
<table style='table-layout:fixed'>
```